# Unconsistent Pandas axis labels

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a pandas data-frame (df) including a column as labels (column 'Specimens' here).

> ```
>   Specimens   Sample  Min_read_lg     Avr_read_lg     Max_read_lg
> 0     B.pleb_sili     1   32                  249.741     488
> 1     B.pleb_sili     2   30                  276.959     489
> 2     B.conc_sili     3   25                  256.294     489
> 3     B.conc_sili     4   27                  277.923     489
> 4     F1_1_sili       5   34                  303.328     489
> ...
> ```

I have tried to plot it as following, but the labels on the x axis are not matching the actual values of the table. Would anyone know why it could be the case?

```
plot=df.plot.area() 
plot.set_xlabel("Specimens")
plot.set_ylabel("Read length")
plot.set_xticklabels(df['Specimens'], rotation=90)
```

I think the "plot.set_xticklabels" method is not right, but I would like to understand why the labels on the x axis are mismatched, and most of them missing.

[image]

Comment: Matplotlib auto scale your ticks, so tick step is not `1`. Try `reads.plot.area(x='Specimens')`. Or you can do `plot.set_xticks(np.range(len(df))` before setting the tick labels.

Comment: Side note: a stacked area plot is probably not appropriate for your data. Stacking min, avg, and max on top of each other doesn't make sense.

Comment: `df.set_index('Specimens', inplace=True)` and then `df.iloc[:, 1:].plot(kind='bar', figsize=(12, 5), rot=0)` is the appropriate plot. [Code and Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIM3v.png).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. I have shifter to a combined barplot as you have demonstrated above, and it is indeed showing the actual data.